# Gridview using SQLDataSource returns "Invalid Column" when linked tables are null

Tags: asp.net, gridview, sqldatasource

I keep getting an error on my asp.net page:

> **Invalid column name 'FirstName'.** 
>   **Invalid column name 'LastName'.**

These are new tables, so the aspnet_users don't have any matching records in Users or contacts.  So, I'm assuming it is blowing up due to the NULL values in first and last name.  Is there a way to tell gridview to just return an empty string?

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdStaff" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
DataSourceID="SqlStaff">
   <Columns>
     <asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" HeaderText="UserName" SortExpression="UserName" />
     <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" SortExpression="FirstName" />
     <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" SortExpression="LastName"  />
     <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Active" HeaderText="Active" SortExpression="Active" />
     <asp:BoundField DataField="LastActivityDate" HeaderText="LastActivityDate" SortExpression="LastActivityDate" />
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlStaff" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VTConnectionString %>" 
SelectCommand="SELECT au.UserId, au.UserName, au.LastActivityDate, Contact.FirstName, Contact.LastName, u.Active FROM Contact RIGHT OUTER JOIN Users AS u ON Contact.ContactID = u.ContactID RIGHT OUTER JOIN aspnet_Users AS au ON u.UserId = au.UserId"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Girish Vadhel: you are right.  I had another sqlDataSource on the page throwing the error.  Once I made its query similar to this one, everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think null values causing error over here, as the error you stated specifies that column names are not matching. You can try with alias in your query like:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlStaff" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VTConnectionString %>" 
SelectCommand="SELECT au.UserId, au.UserName, au.LastActivityDate, Contact.FirstName as FirstName, Contact.LastName as LastName, u.Active FROM Contact RIGHT OUTER JOIN Users AS u ON Contact.ContactID = u.ContactID RIGHT OUTER JOIN aspnet_Users AS au ON u.UserId = au.UserId"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```